# SharePoint 2013 Regional setting for start and end time

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am new in SharePoint development,I am facing some issues while setting up regional Settings start and end time

Steps:

- Go to regional settings and
- Set Start time : 6:00 PM and End Time 12:00 AM

As it is considering 12:00 AM to next date which is correct
but many of our forms stopped working due to this setting

Does SharePoint support this type of Scenario? where start and End time is between two days?

Comment: many of our forms stopped working due to this setting ? what's this form is it InfoPath form or default form ? what's this form do , I applied your scenario with default form and everything is working properly